# Query for tables with foreign key in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, foreign-keys

I have 2 tables **SjohlLBzads_products** & **SjohlLBzads_products_meta** connected by column (post_id) as foreign key.

How do I create queries on multiple tables ?

Controller function which I have right now only makes query to a single table (SjohlLBzads_products).

I would like to display shipping column in SjohlLBzads_products_meta together with other columns from the current table.

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->library('lib_pagination');                         
    $pg_config['sql']      = "SELECT * from SjohlLBzads_products";              
    $pg_config['per_page'] = 50;                                     
    $data = $this->lib_pagination->create_pagination($pg_config);   

    $this->load->view("product_listing", $data);
```

Thanks!

Comment: You mean a join?

Comment: yes and display on the same page in html table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a JOIN statement

```
$pg_config['sql'] = "SELECT * FROM SjohlLBzads_products 
            JOIN johlLBzads_products_meta 
            ON johlLBzads_products.post_id = johlLBzads_products_meta.post_id ";
```

Comment: It's working in the controller but how do I call it in the view ? Calling it using below codes gave me error : 

<?php echo $data->Shipping; ?>

Comment: I cannot help with that without knowing what `$data` looks like. And that is probably another question. :)